# How can I transfer emails from MS Outlook to Yahoo?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, transfer, yahoo-mail

For the first time I use MS Outlook 2007 for Yahoo Mail and I've configured it. All of the emails have downloaded from the Yahoo server and to Outlook and as a result, the Yahoo inbox is completely empty.

How can I undo it and add the mail back to my Yahoo inbox (about 300 emails)?

Comment: I updated your question, if you don't like it, [roll it back](http://superuser.com/posts/641277/revisions). Please confirm if you set this up as a Pop3 account?

Comment: Uh oh, you didn't see the setting to `leave Mail on server`

Answer (score 3):

In respond to Dave Rook, he has given me an idea how to set up IMAP in MS Outlook.  I have the same issue like you did. I set up Pop3 yahoo for my MS Outlook.  I never unchecked the box saying "Delete mails from the server after downloading to my MS Outlook.  I did not like the idea of forwarding all my emails from MS Outlook to Yahoo again.

Here is the solution.

Do not delete Pop3 yahoo account from MS Outlook. If you did that, you will eventually delete all your emails in MS Outlook.

Now, create IMAP account.
IMAP configuration has to match below

Incoming Mail (IMAP) Server - Requires SSL

Server: imap.mail.yahoo.com
Port: 993
Requires SSL: Yes
Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server - Requires TLS

Server: smtp.mail.yahoo.com
Port: 465 or 587
Requires SSL: Yes
Requires authentication: Yes

Once you have done that, go ahead and synchronize with the yahoo server.  Make sure you input your username and password correctly.  After MS Outlook has downloaded all the yahoo mails into MS Outlook IMAP configuration, perform copy and paste of all the missing emails into your IMAP configuration folder from Pop3 configuration mail folder in your MS Outlook.
Once you have pasted all the email, click send and receive to synchronize with yahoo server.  Once done, open your web browser, log into yahoo mail.  You will see all your missing mails are back into the server.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

What you've probably done is created a pop3 account which is set up to remove it from the server on download.

You can't undo this process unless Yahoo! mail has a back up feature. However, there are ways to restore it.

You are probably best to do a few things. First is, change the settings in Outlook to not delete from the server (or at least, keep a few months worth of data) or even review IMAP (details about this further down this post).

In regards to getting them back I would bite the bullet and start emailing all the emails to yourself. This of course is not only laborious but also has other negative effects such as filtering. You also need to do this after you change your email settings in Outlook.

Option 1

Create a new account but use IMAP as this will keep a copy on the server. Then, this should sync them back automatically!

Option 2

Keep it as a Pop3 account, open up the account options in Outlook (File, account settings, account settings). Double click on the email in question, click on advanced tab and then in the new window, the last tab (I think called Advanced (doing this from memory)) will have an option to delete from server or to keep for X amount of days.